# Weird dynamic type parameter issue

Tags: c#, .net

Simple code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic income = "test";
        var result = Test(income); // Why dynamic?
        Test2(result); // WTF?
    }

    static string Test(string income)
    {
        return income;
    }

    static string Test2(int income)
    {
        return income.ToString();
    }
}
```

The above code compiles with no errors and executes with an exception at runtime: `An unhandled exception of type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll`

Can anyone explain why `result` is determined as `dynamic` type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pass a `dynamic` value to an expression, that entire expression becomes `dynamic`.

The whole point of dynamic is to turn off all type-checking; the compiler will always assume `dynamic`, even if the code is obviously wrong.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: This is part of the core behavior of `dynamic`; look in its documentation.